# How to access angularjs sessionStorage value to entire project?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, session, storage

I need login values for the entire project.so I'm using rootScope, but if my page is refreshed, the rootScope value gets destroyed.
so instead of rootScope, I'm using AngularJS sessionStorage and now value sets successfully. Now I need to use sessionStorage value for the entire project.

how to use sessionStorage value wherever I want. I am looking for a positive replay.

**Controller**

```
if(response.data.status != null)
{   
    scope.User=response;
    rootScope.UserId=response.data.UserId;
     $window.sessionStorage.setItem("id",response.data.UserId);
     scope.id = $window.sessionStorage.getItem("id");
    state.go("userHome");
}
```

Thank you..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create accessors on the $rootScope inside the "app.run" :

```
angular.module("myApp").run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope){
    var id = null;    
    $rootScope.getId = function(){
        if (!id) id = sessionStorage.getItem('id');

        return id;        
    };

    $rootScope.setId = function(userId) {
        id = userId;
        sessionStorage.setItem('id', userId);
    };

}]);
```

- That way, you can keep on using your id inside views, you will just have to make a call.
- You won't forget to check sessionStorage if the $rootScope has no value set.
- You won't have to access sessionStorage every time you need the id (querying the session storage is way slower than getting an item on the heap)

You will simply have to use it like the following :

```
if(response.data.status != null)
{   
    scope.User=response;
    rootScope.setId(response.data.UserId);
    scope.id = rootScope.getId();
    state.go("userHome");
}
```

## For accessing it into your views :

### version 1.5+ :

you can simply bind it to the "controller as" provided by $rootscope :

```
<div>{{$root.getId()}}</div>
```

### version 1.5- :

As far as you never have a method or property bound to a `$scope` named `getId`, the following will work thanks to scope inheritance (if you don't know about scope inheritance in angular, you really should spend some time googling it)

```
<div>{{getId()}}</div>
```

Comment: can i use localStorage instead of sessionStorage?

Comment: juste replace sessionStorage by localStorage

Comment: Thank you. how to use sessionStorage value in  different pages.

Comment: if you are using angular 1.5+, you can use it like `{{$root.getId()}}`

Comment: i'm using 1.4.8 angular version.how to use this version